# get modifierFlags in keyDown event without pressing non-modifier key along with it!

Tags: objective-c, events, handle, keydown, modifier

I have subclassed NSWindow in a NSDocument application in order to receive keyDown events.

I have used the following code in my subclasss...

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSLog(@"keyDown!");

    if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask) {
        NSLog(@"Alt key Down!");
    }
    else
        [super keyDown:theEvent];
}
```

I'm receiving key events when non-modifier keys are pressed!
I'm also receiving "Alt Key is Down" when I press alt+z for example (alt+non-modifierkey).

The issue here is that I want to handle the event when just the alt/option key is pressed alone, without in combination with other keys and -keyDown: does not get called! What am I missing ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could catch the Alt/Option key alone [in `-flagsChanged:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/flagsChanged:) instead of `-keyDown:`.

```
-(void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask) {
        NSLog(@"Alt key Down (again)!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't I need to forward theEven to super ? Probably not ha?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
-(void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    [super flagsChanged:theEvent];
    if ((([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask) & NSAlternateKeyMask) > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Alt key Down (again)!");
    }
}
```